# 301 redirect from one domain to another but only for specific pages

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

We are rebuilding a website for a client from ASP to WordPress. This website will have a different domain, url structure, and file extension. I am only just getting my head around htaccess 301 redirects, and I know enough that I can't do the following:

```
Redirect 301 http://www.site1.com/about_us.asp https://site2.com/about/
Redirect 301 http://www.site1.com/art-specs/ https://site2.com/specs/
Redirect 301 http://www.site1.com/page/product1/ https://site2.com/product1/
```

There are about 12 links in total that need to be redirected, and I want to make sure that it is done right the first time as a client's SEO rankings are on the line.

Is there a variation of the above format that I could use? Or a rewrite rule that needs to be done first? Any help (and explanations) would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: A simple look into the excellent documentation of apache's alias module would have shown you that the second argument to the `Redirect` directive is a _path_, not an _URL_ : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking more into it, I realised that the htaccess file shouldn't need anything other than relative access to the original domain.

i.e. You shouldn't need to declare: `http://www.site1.com/about_us.asp` since the server and domain should be configured in such a way that `/about_us.asp` means the same thing.

So the correct answer would be to:

[1] Configure the server (in my case cPanel) by having the original domain added as an addon domain (e.g `http://www.site1.com/`).

[2] In the htaccess file I would add each of the 301 redirects to the htaccess file:

```
Redirect 301 /about_us.asp https://site2.com/about/
Redirect 301 /art-specs/ https://site2.com/specs/
Redirect 301 /page/product1/ https://site2.com/product1/

...for each redirect
```

[3] And finally, adding the following to the bottom of the htaccess file will catch everything else and redirect them to the home page:

```
RedirectMatch 301 .* https://site2.com
```